# How to make Angular @mentions library let you select a single choice multiple times?

Tags: angular

I'm using a @flxng/mentions library in my Angular project (which is great, btw, you can find it [here](https://github.com/seidme/flxng)), and it does not allow me to select a single item multiple times (only one is being counted as a choice, and fires a `choiceSelected` event).

How can I change this behaviour?